# Fake caller ID on text messages using Twilio (or any other provider)

Tags: c#, sms, telephony, twilio

Simple question:
How can I send a text message using Twilio, or any other provider, with fake caller ID?

I'm using [Twilio REST API (C#)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install/).

**EDIT:**

I found this company which provides this future, but they are far too pricey:
http://www.smsmessagesender.com/SmsApi

Does anyone knows a better alternative?

Comment: I want my app to send an invitation to use my app via SMS, and I want the receiver to see the message like it came from the user's phone.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We (Twilio) don't allow this because it's ripe for abuse.. for example, I could send out 1000 messages with your number as the From. Then you get all the responses.

Comment: What about using my business name as the sender? Can I do that using Twilio?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't set the name, just the phone number.

Comment: Just like email aliases, which are also ripe for abuse, this is a useful feature to have for businesses. Telecommunications services should monitor and block abuse like how spam is treated, rather than not have the feature at all. I suspect the real reason is that some services just don't want to spend resources implementing the feature. In any case, there *are* services out there offering something. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, it's a carrier thing. In the US, generally speaking, any SMS traffic has to be from a number you 'own'. For APIs, that would be one or more virtual numbers you purchase.

Outside the US - again, generally speaking - there's more freedom in what you can use. However, different APIs may or may not choose to expose that. For example, with [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com) you can set the sender ID to whatever you want, with countries / carriers where that's supported.

As to what countries / carriers support a dynamic sender ID, this [Nexmo Country FAQ](https://nexmo.zendesk.com/categories/20079687-Country-Specifics) may be helpful (even if you're using a different API).

(*Disclaimer: I do some developer evangelism for Nexmo.*)

Comment: @Tim Lytle, does Nexmo still support such a feature? The Country FAQ link you posted no longer exists. I need it for Asia, and my specific requirement is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856753/change-from-field-of-sms-text-message-for-recipient

Answer (score 1):

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856753/change-from-field-of-sms-text-message-for-recipient) and found three services (not Twilio):

- Nexmo
- Plivo
- smsmessagesender

The above services support dynamic alphanumeric sender ID for *outbound* SMS, so you should be able to send a combination of 11 alpha-numeric characters as the sender ID of your message. Note the emphasis on outbound SMS. It appears that receiving incoming SMS on an alphanumeric sender ID is not possible.

Edit: as mentioned in other answers, the availability of these services also depends on the laws of the jurisdiction where the services are to be used.

Comment: The above is correct. This is useful for marketing messages where you are not expecting a response. A response must be made to a true CLI. (Ie "Claim PPI Now. Call us 0800 XXX XXXX")

Answer (score 0):

Plivo allows custom caller id for calls... try it

Comment: I don't thing they support this future for text messages. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lidor You are correct, at least in the US. For the most part it's a carrier thing, not an API thing.

Comment: @Lidor, yes, they do support it for text messages. Also depends on the laws of the jurisdiction. See my answer.