# Make a phone call from C#

Tags: c#, api, phone-call

I live in a security complex, and to open the gate you have to phone a number, which is inconvenient when only ONE phone can open the gate! If I was to lose or forget my phone, no entry. So that's the back-story.

I want to be able to make a phone call to our gate system, from a C# app. It must look like it is comming from my current number, and because it only needs to dial (The line is never actually answered) I would prefer a free service.

Can someone please point me to such an API? I want to be able to only use an internet connection to make this phone call. I was looking at Twilio, but to test it, I need to pay. (Probably in case the call is answered, or they charge for the dialing time, that's the thing, I don't know how their charging is made, but I know the call is never answered, and would love to dial for free)[image: Very detailed schematic]

Comment: What kind of place is that? Doesn't sound too friendly...

Comment: Tell me about it. Someone complained that the intercom system is being misused (She was in the first unit, and so anyone that wanted to come in called her unit) and long story short, intercom system has been removed.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219499/fake-caller-id-on-text-messages-using-twilio-or-any-other-provider
(Hoping we're not helping you to gain unauthorized access to the building...)

Comment: Don't know if that would be possible, as with twilio I had to verify my phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this may help.

```
    using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks! However, I see that this only applies to windows phone...

Answer (score 2):

You can use AT Command, send an AT command to the port:

> [Using Basic AT Modem Commands](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164659)
>   [Hayes command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command)

Comment: I think this might require a connected modem? I want to be able to send the command from a pc connected to the internet.

Comment: @Corne How do you have access to a PC with internet in front of your building?

Comment: Good question. It is not necessarily a PC, but the first implementation will be. I will probably make it into a android or IOS app (Using Unity3D, in which you have access to the .Net framework, and write C# code)

Comment: @Corne An app that would run on your... Phone?

Comment: Or tablet! I see where you are going... But I don't want to limit it to just phones.