# Change "from" field of SMS text message for recipient

Tags: sms, twilio

I want the recipient of my SMS text message to see the name of my business, rather than the phone number. How is this possible? I am currently using Twilio, but I am open to suggestions involving other services.

Comment: Highly doubtful that you can do this - SMS doesn't have a "sender name" field, only number. For what it's worth, even AT&T doesn't make a name appear when sending billing SMSs, and they run the network.

Comment: How about some clever solution like adding a link that upon user approval adds the number to the user's contact list. Not sure how to do that right now, though. I am also in contact with Twilio support to see what is possible.

Comment: Yes. You can send a Service Indication sms message, commonly referred to as a WAP Push message to send a URL that will automatically load in the browser when received.

Comment: I know from experience that some countries in Asia allow what the questions asks for. However, Twilio does not allow it for the reasons listed: spam, inability to block/unsubscribe, and legality depending on location. https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found three services (not Twilio) that appear to address the question:

- Nexmo
- Plivo
- smsmessagesender

The above services support dynamic alphanumeric sender ID for *outbound* SMS, so you should be able to send a combination of 11 alpha-numeric characters as the sender ID of your message. Note the emphasis on outbound SMS. It appears that receiving incoming SMS on an alphanumeric sender ID is not possible.

If anyone has more experience with these services, please share.

Edit: Note that the availability of these services also depends on the laws of the jurisdiction where the services are to be used.

Comment: I am using dynamic sender id (from Plivo) in my app and it works. But remember that not all countries support this!!!

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who have looked at @philnash s answer and still having problems, please read this. I'm using the twilio-ruby gem, and am in the UK.

I see a lot of places state that:

> all you need to do is replace the `from` parameter.

**This is not true!**

**Step 1**

Contact Twilio and have them enabled it on your account.

**Step 2**

The second step is to make sure that to number you are using has the correct country code, `0779XXXXXXX` and `779XXXXXXX` are enough to send a text message when specifying a `from` number that has been previously purchased. The purchased number has a country of origin and therefore Twilio know to prefix it with the correct country code. However, an alphanumeric sender has no from number, and therefore no country of origin.

Using `0779XXXXXXX` as the `To` param. Returns the error:

```
The 'To' number 0779XXXXXXX is not a valid phone number.
```

While technically correct, it isn't incorrect, it's just missing the country code.

Using `779XXXXXXX` as the `To` param. Returns this error: `The 'To' phone number: +1779XXXXXXX, is not currently reachable using the 'From' phone number: Foo via SMS.` +1 is the USA phone prefix. The USA doesn't have an option to send as alphanumeric. This is how I stumbled onto the fix.

**TLDR;**

**1. Contact Twilio to get them to enable it on your account**

**2. Make sure you prefix with the country code.**

Comment: Hey @DickieBoy, with regards to your second point, the documentation does say you need to [format the number as E.164](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-required) (that is, with international prefix). It is confusing slightly because US numbers do not require the international prefix (which is why the error message added +1 to one of those numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I know this is a good few months since you asked this, but I wanted to update the possible answers for completeness. When you asked this in November 2014 it was not possible to send SMS messages from Twilio using an alphanumeric sender ID.

However, [since May 2015 it has been possible to do so](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/05/introducing-6-new-international-phone-numbers-and-alphanumeric-sender-id.html). All you need to do is replace the phone number as the `From` parameter of the API call to send a message with the text you want the sender ID to be. This currently works when sending SMS messages to [145 countries](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-countries-does-twilio-support-alphanumeric-sender-id).

If I was doing this in Ruby, it would look like:

```
account_sid = YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
auth_token = YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
recipient_phone_number = RECIPIENT_PHONE_NUMBER

client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
client.messages.create(
  from: "ALPHANUMERICID",
  to: recipient_phone_number,
  body: "Hello World!"
)
```

**Edit**

Please note, that to use alphanumeric sender IDs on your Twilio account you need to have your account enabled. To do so, please [contact twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with your account SID to request access.

Comment: Isn't the "from" supposed to hold the alph. id?

Comment: Hi @philnash could you take a look at my answer, see if anything can be done to help developers who also come across the problem I faced.

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks @DickieBoy. This changed recently, didn't used to have to get access to this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is there a place within twilio panel i set this name? I can't find it anywhere, or I'm free to put what ever i want? Ie: from: "cocacocla" I'm getting errors

Comment: @Manza you need to [contact Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and ask to get this enabled on your account now. Send them your account SID and they will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, we'll the account already came enabled, but no were in the account i can find where to set the alphanumeric to a specific name. The support keep saying just to replace the from but I'm sure somewhere in the account i have to verify this name right?

Comment: If your account is enabled to send messages from an alphanumeric ID then you can either set that in the call you make to the API by replacing your `From` number with with the string, like in the example in my answer above, or you can add it to a [messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/services).

Answer (score 0):

As FullStack said, you can consider using another SMS API for this.

Nexmo, where I work, offers a high quality messaging service including the support of dynamic sender id. You can use any alphanumeric string to describe your application or brand where supported by carriers (where there are no restrictions on alphanumeric sender ids).

Some countries, such as the United States, don't allow alphanumeric sender ids. Other countries allow it, but have special restrictions that we take into account & work around to ensure maximum delivery.

You can find the full list of alpha-numeric sender ID compatible countries, along with carrier restrictions, [here](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/sections/200622473-Country-Specific-Features-and-Restrictions?page=1).

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query([
    'api_key' => API_KEY,
    'api_secret' => API_SECRET,
    'to' => YOUR_NUMBER,
    'from' => "AppName",
    'text' => 'Hello'
]);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Would sending STOP to an alphanumeric sender ID trigger a callback?